# Considerations about $y'' + 3y'^2 = \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f: \ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ solves that differential equation, it's not so hard to show that if $f$ has an extreme point at $c$, $c \neq 0$, then that extreme is a minimum point of $f$.

But if $c = 0$, does $c$ can be a an extreme point? If yes, would it be a point of maximum or minimum?

I was thinking about $$\lim_{x \to 0} f''(x) + 3f'(x)^2 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x}$$
Using L'Hôpital rule we can conclude that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x} =\lim_{x \to 0} e^{-x} = 1$. As $c$ is an extreme point then f'(c) = 0, therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} f''(x) = 1 > 0$ (minimum point).

However, this does not seem to have convinced me. Is that idea enough?

Comment: Just about notation: Use $f'(x)$, not $f(x)'$.

Comment: And yes, this works for any value of $c$, including $0$, since $\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Ah! ok, isn't that hard as i thought

Comment: based on this and considering that $f(0) = 0$, can we find a constant $A$ such that $f(x) \leq Ax^2$?